# Create index with dynamic typing and property list

Tags: elasticsearch

I currently have docs of the format:

```
{
  name: string 
  foo: integer or string
}
```

and:

```
   "mappings": {
      "users": {
         "properties": {
            "name": {
               "type": "string",
               "index_analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer",
               "search_analyzer": "standard"
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

This currently sees `foo` as an integer when the first doc gets processed and errors when it comes across a doc where `foo` is a string – so I need to set `foo` to be a dynamic type. I would also like to be able to, later on, send docs to ES with additional dynamic-type properties without deleting and recreating the index, eg:

```
{
  name: string
  foo: int or string
  bar: int or string
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just declare it as a String so it matches both integers AND strings ? Basically your integers will get converted to Strings but I can't think of a reason this should be problematic, since you have to parse carefully when you retrieve your data in any case, whether it's dynamic or fixed as a String that contains Integers.

Comment: Oh I didn't know they get converted, thanks! Do you also happen to know about having the index allow addition of doc properties later on?

Comment: If by doc properties you mean mapping types into the index, I don't think that is possible. That being said you can still add documents with different/new fields even if they don't match your initial mapping. They'll be mapped by default.